# Query to get date rows older than a start date (not a simple WHERE)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a feeling this is quite simple, but I can't put my finger on the query. I'm trying to find all of the activities of an employee which corresponds to their start date in a specific location.

```
create table Locations (EmployeeID int, LocationID int, StartDate date);

create table Activities (EmployeeID int, ActivityID int, [Date] date);

insert into Locations values 
    (1, 10, '01-01-2010')
    , (1, 11, '01-01-2012')
    , (1, 11, '01-01-2013');

insert into Activities values 
    (1, 1, '02-01-2010')
    , (1, 2, '04-01-2010')
    , (1, 3, '06-06-2014');
```

Expected result:

```
EmployeeID  LocationID  StartDate       EmployeeID  ActivityID  Date
1           10          '01-01-2010'    1           1           '02-01-2010'
1           10          '01-01-2010'    1           2           '04-01-2010'
1           11          '01-01-2013'    1           3           '06-06-2014'
```

So far, I have this, but it's not quite giving me the result I was hoping for. I somehow have to reference only the information from the most recent Location, which the `la.StartDate <= a.Date` does not filter out and includes information from older locations as well.

```
select *
from Locations la
    inner join Activities a on la.EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID
        and la.StartDate <= a.Date
```

Comment: This is bad database design. There should be a FK in the Activities table to the Locations table.

Comment: @mxix I agree, but this is what I have to work with..

Comment: Can you introduce an EndDate in Locations? That would simplify things a bit.

Comment: @NickyvV Not really, but that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, but I managed to find the answer:

```
select *
from LocationAssociations la
    inner join Activities a on la.EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID
        and la.StartDate = (select max(StartDate) from LocationAssociations where StartDate >= la.StartDate and StartDate <= a.Date)
```

Comment: you probably don't need `and la.StartDate <= a.date`

Comment: @JamieD77 Yes, you're right, since the second condition in the JOIN is more restrictive. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try:

```
with Locations as (
select
*
from (values 
    (1, 10, '01-01-2010')
    , (1, 11, '01-01-2012')
    , (1, 11, '01-01-2013')
) la (EmployeeID, LocationID, StartDate)
),
Activities as (
select
*
from (
values
    (1, 1, '02-01-2010')
    , (1, 2, '04-01-2010')
    , (1, 3, '06-06-2014')
) a (EmployeeID, ActivityID, [Date])
)
select 
    la.*,
    a.*
from Activities a
cross apply (
    select
    *
    from (
        select 
            la.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY
                    EMPLOYEEID
                ORDER BY
                    DATE DESC
            ) seqnum
        from Locations la 
        where 
            la.EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID and 
            la.StartDate <= a.Date
    ) la
    where
        la.seqnum = 1
) la
```

Comment: This doesn't get the correct location for the last row, you always end up with location 1 (due to `la.seqnum=1`).